# Concurrent Tasks and different cursor positions for each of them

Tags: c#, task

I am starting to practice with Tasks and I tried the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Write('a', 0);
    });

    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        Write('b', 10);
    });

    t.Start();

    Write('c', 20);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Write(char c, int x)
{
    int yCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, yCounter);
        yCounter++;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

My idea was to see how the console will go between the three different columns to output the different characters. It does swap the columns, but it does not output the correct characters. For example, in the first column it needs to output only 'a', but it also outputs 'b' and 'c', same goes for the other 2 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a particularly bad example of using tasks - or an example of how to use tasks badly.

Within your tasks you are setting a global state (`SetCursorPosition`), which will of course affect the other tasks (`Console` is static after all). It's possible that

```
Console.WriteLine('b')
```

is called after the cursor has been set to `0`, to `10` or to `20`, vice versa for the other values. Tasks should not rely on any global (or class level) state that might have changed (except if it's okay for the task that the value might have changed). With regards to your example, you would have to assure that none of the other tasks call `SetCursorPosition` before you have written your output. The easiest way to achieve this is locking the task

```
private static object lockObject = new object(); // you need an object of a reference type for locking

static void Write(char c, int x)
{
    int yCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, yCounter);
            Console.Write(c);
        }

        yCounter++;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

The `lock` assures that no two tasks enter the block at a time (given that the lock object is the very *same*), hence each task can set the cursor to the position it wants to write at and write its char without any other tasks setting the cursor to any other position. (Plus, I've swapped `Write` and `SetCursorPosition`, since we'll have to call `SetCursorPosition` before writing to the output - the lock would be useless without swappinng those two lines, anyway.)

Comment: Thank you! I understand how this might be a bad way to use tasks, I am simply trying to learn more about them and come up with interesting examples :) But I understand your point, I've heard about locks before and I thought that it may be related! Thank you!

Comment: It is working correctly, however I noticed that it always executes the Tasks in the exact same order, always first is 'c', then 'a', then 'b', since this is always happening, there must be a reason for it and its not just a random process. Do you know the reason? (I moved the thread.sleep within the look and that is how I saw the order of which task is getting executed)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Paul's answer.

If you're dealing with tasks and `async`/`await`, don't mix `Task` and `Thread` in any way.

Executing your `Write` method using `Task.Run`/`Task.Start` is called "async-over-sync". This is a bad practice, and should be avoided.

Here's your code, rewritten in async manner, with async synchronization:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asyncLock = new AsyncLock();

        // we need ToList here, since IEnumerable is lazy, 
        // and must be enumerated to produce values (tasks in this case);
        // WriteAsync call inside Select produces a "hot" task - task, that is already scheduled;
        // there's no need to start hot tasks explicitly - they are already started
        new[] { ('a', 0), ('b', 10), ('c', 20) }
            .Select(_ => WriteAsync(_.Item1, _.Item2, asyncLock))
            .ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task WriteAsync(char c, int x, AsyncLock asyncLock)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            using (await asyncLock.LockAsync())
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, i);
                Console.Write(c);
            }

            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

`AsyncLock` lives in [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) package.